# SELECT statements within a function - alias, with, temp tables...etc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a function where the user inputs a date then receives a table.
The function returns the table that shows for every day (transdate) what type of mail came in and how many, then a running total specific to each mail type is generated.  It works fine as a select statement, but when I try and put in function format I receive the error:
"Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client."

```
CREATE FUNCTION DailyMailCount(@Date datetime)
RETURNS @Count TABLE 
                    (
   [ID] int identity (1,1),
   Transdate datetime, 
   Donation varchar (10), 
   DailyCount int,  
   RunningTotal int    
                     ) 

AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @running_total TABLE (Transdate DATETIME,Donation varchar(30), countz INT,row int)
INSERT INTO @running_total

SELECT TransDate,Donation, COUNT(*)
,ROW_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Donation order by TransDate ASC) as row 
FROM RevInt.DetailDonation WHERE TransDate > '@Date' GROUP BY TransDate,Donation

SELECT 
r1.Transdate,
r1.Donation,
r1.countz,
SUM(r2.countz) as running_total
FROM @running_total r1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @running_total r2 on r2.donation = r1.Donation
                AND r2.row <= r1.row
GROUP BY 
r1.transdate,
r1.countz,
r1.donation,
r1.row
ORDER BY r1.Donation

       RETURN 
END
```

Comment: This looks like a stored procedure, not a function.

Comment: I am new to functions and stored procedures.  Could you briefly explain to me why this should be a SP?

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DailyMailCount(@Date datetime)
RETURNS @Count TABLE (
   [ID] int identity (1,1),
   Transdate datetime, 
   Donation varchar (10), 
   DailyCount int,  
   RunningTotal int    
) 
as begin
    DECLARE @running_total TABLE (Transdate DATETIME,Donation varchar(30), countz INT,row int)
    INSERT INTO @running_total
        SELECT TransDate,Donation, COUNT(*),
               ROW_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Donation order by TransDate ASC) as row 
        FROM DetailDonation
        WHERE TransDate > '@Date'
        GROUP BY TransDate, Donation;

    insert into @Count
        SELECT r1.Transdate, r1.Donation, r1.countz,
               SUM(r2.countz) as running_total
        FROM @running_total r1
             LEFT OUTER JOIN @running_total r2
             on r2.donation = r1.Donation AND r2.row <= r1.row
        GROUP BY r1.transdate, r1.countz, r1.donation, r1.row
        ORDER BY r1.Donation;

    RETURN;
END;
```

You are missing the `insert` into the return table.

You can also create an in-line function (one statement) by using a single query:

```
return with running_total as (
    SELECT TransDate,Donation, COUNT(*),
           ROW_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Donation order by TransDate ASC) as row 
    FROM RevInt.DetailDonation
    WHERE TransDate > '@Date'
    GROUP BY TransDate,Donation
)
SELECT r1.Transdate, r1.Donation, r1.countz, SUM(r2.countz) as running_total
FROM running_total r1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     running_total r2
     on r2.donation = r1.Donation
                AND r2.row <= r1.row
GROUP BY r1.transdate, r1.countz, r1.donation, r1.row
ORDER BY r1.Donation
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you correcltly.  Would you mind copying and pasting my original code posting and showing me how you would change it?

Comment: @user2200270 . . . I fixed it.  My original answer was just in the wrong direction.